# PDE Separation Of Variables: Laplace Equation Problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am having trouble with this problem. Here is the problem:

I might need some tips on how to go through this problem. I have a sense on solving the cases for the separation constant, but I am having trouble on how to do it in this scenario. Here's the question:

Solve Laplace’s equation 
$[u_{xx}+u_{yy} = 0.]$ (This equation should be in polar form)

inside a circular annulus $R_1 < r < R_2$ with boundary conditions: $\varphi(R_1,\theta) = 0$ and 
$\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial r} (R_2,θ) = f(θ)$

I understand the process of Separation Of Variables and the Laplace Equation. The point I am stuck on at the moment is evaluating the Boundary Condition and the Initial Condition.

Also, this is my first time on this website and I am trying to get familiar with it. I might need some tips on how to input in these figures correctly.

Comment: Could you walk us up to the point you get stuck? Do you know the circular laplacian, for example?

Comment: I have already edited the question. The only thing I am confused on is trying to evaluate the boundary condition and the initial condition for each case for the separation constant, K.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual separation of variables in polar coordinates produces

$$\phi \left( r,\theta \right) =\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \left( A_{{n}}\sin
 \left( n\theta \right) +B_{{n}}\cos \left( n\theta \right)  \right) 
 \left( {r}^{n}C_{{n}}+{r}^{-n}E_{{n}} \right) +F\ln  \left( r
 \right)$$

which is rewritten as

$$\phi \left( r,\theta \right) =\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \left( A_{{n}}\sin
 \left( n\theta \right) +B_{{n}}\cos \left( n\theta \right)  \right) 
 \left( {r}^{n}C_{{n}}+{r}^{-n}E_{{n}} \right) +G+ F\ln  \left( r
 \right)$$
Applying the boundary condition at $r=R_1$  we obtain

$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \left( A_{{n}}\sin \left( n\theta \right) +B_{{n
}}\cos \left( n\theta \right)  \right)  \left( {R_{{1}}}^{n}C_{{n}}+{R
_{{1}}}^{-n}E_{{n}} \right) +F\ln  \left( R_{{1}} \right) +G =0
$$

From this last equation we derive that $G=-Fln(R_1)$  and

$${R_{{1}}}^{n}C_{{n}}+{R_{{1}}}^{-n}E_{{n}}= 0$$

Then we have

$$ E_{{n}}=-{R_{{1}}}^{2\,n}C_{{n}} $$

The solution takes the form

$$\phi \left( r,\theta \right) =\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \left( A_{{n}}\sin
 \left( n\theta \right) +B_{{n}}\cos \left( n\theta \right)  \right) 
 \left( {r}^{n}-{r}^{-n}{R_{{1}}}^{2\,n} \right)-Fln(R_1)+Fln(r) 
$$

Applying the boundary condition at $r=R_2$ we obtain

$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \left( A_{{n}}\sin \left( n\theta \right) +B_{{n
}}\cos \left( n\theta \right)  \right) n \left( {R_{{2}}}^{n-1}+{R_{{2
}}}^{-n-1}{R_{{1}}}^{2\,n} \right)+F/R_2 =f \left( \theta \right) 
$$

Finally the constants $F$, $A_n$ and $B_n$ are determined using the standard expressions of Fourier series.

Comment: Okay I understand this concept. Is this for the condition when the separation constant is greater than zero?

Comment: I guess I do not know how you got $n\theta$ for $F(\theta)$ and I do not understand how you got   $r^n$ and $r^{-n}$ from the very beginning of your work.

Comment: Hi @Juan Ospina, I do not understand what you mean.

Comment: Okay here is the work I have:   Use Separation of Variables so assume the solution $\phi (r,\theta)$ = $F(r)G(\theta)$.          By Separation of Variables, it would form out to                    $\frac{r}{F}$ $\frac{\partial}{\partial r}$ $r (\frac{\partial F}{\partial r}) = \lambda$

Comment: Sorry, I am trying to get familiar with Latex. It is my first time on this website. Here is what I edited:                      Okay here is the work I have:   Use Separation of Variables so assume the solution $\phi (r,\theta)$ = $F(r)G(\theta)$.          By Separation of Variables, it would form out to                    $\frac{r}{F}$ $\frac{\partial}{\partial r}$ $r (\frac{\partial F}{\partial r}) = -\lambda F$   For the function $G(\theta)$, I got $\frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial^2 \theta} = \lambda G$. I only made observations for the cases of $\lambda$ for $F(R)$.

Comment: Okay, solving your equations you obtain  $$F \left( r \right) ={\it C_1}\,{r}^{\sqrt {\lambda}}+{\it C_2}\,{r}^
{-\sqrt {\lambda}}
$$  $$ G \left( \theta \right) ={\it A_1}\,\sin \left( \sqrt {\lambda}\theta
 \right) +{\it A_2}\,\cos \left( \sqrt {\lambda}\theta \right) 
> 
$$   Given that G must be a periodic function of $\theta$ it is necessary to make $\sqrt {\lambda}=n$ where $n$ is an integer.  Then the solution is a sum for all values of $n$.  Do you agree?

Comment: Given that you need to solve a problem inside a circular region only the case with $\lambda>0$ is admissible.  Do you agree?

Comment: I got that we need to solve the case for $\lambda > 0$, but I do not understand why we set $\sqrt \lambda = n$

Comment: Now pay attention to the equation for $G \left( \theta \right)$. When $\lambda >0$ you obtain trigonometric functions. You need periodic solutions respect to  $\theta$ and a function of the form $sin(c\theta)$ is periodic only when $c$ is an integer.  For this reason you must to make $\sqrt {\lambda}=n$.  Do you agree?

Comment: Oh okay that makes more sense now. Thank you for your help and for your patience. I really appreciate it.

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: One more thing, I am not sure if I am computing the constants in the Fourier Series. I have $A_0 = \frac{1}{n2\pi(R_1^{n-1} + R_1^{-n-1} R_2^{2n})} \[\int_0^{2\pi} F(\theta) d\theta.\]$.     I have                                                           $A_n = \frac{1}{n\pi(R_1^{n-1} + R_1^{-n-1} R_2^{2n})}           \[\int_0^{2\pi} F(\theta) \sin(n\theta) d\theta.\]$. Is this right? If it is, I should be able to compute $B_n$

Comment: Hi @SSivetts, please look the little modifications in the computation above.  Then $$F=\frac{1}{2} \,{\frac {\int _{0}^{2\,\pi }\!f \left( \theta \right) {d\theta}R
_{{2}}}{\pi }}
$$ 
 Your expression for $A_n$  is correct and with a similar expression for $B_n$.  All the best.

Comment: Okay that makes more sense. Thank you for all your help again. I wish you the best as well.