# Laplace Equation on a circular strip

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

I am currently working on solving 
$$
\begin{cases}
\Delta u = 0,\ \ 1 < r < 2\\
u(1,\theta) = 0, \ \ u(2, \theta) = \sin(\theta)
\end{cases}
$$
After making the ansatz $u(r,\theta) = R(r)\Theta(\theta)$ I have separated the equation into
$$
\Theta(\theta) = \mathcal{A}e^{im\theta},\ \ \forall\mathcal{A}\ \in\ \mathbb{C}
$$
and solved the Cauchy-Euler equation to find
$$
R(r) = Br^m + Cr^{-m}
$$
On a circular disk I am used to discarding the constant $C$ as the solution must be bounded at $r = 0$, but in this case however, I am unsure as to how to use the boundary conditions to find my constants $\mathcal{A}, B$ and $C$. To find $\mathcal{A}$ I suppose the second boundary condition should suffice, but the radial equation has got me confused.

Any insights are much appreciated.

Comment: This might be useful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/951755/pde-separation-of-variables-laplace-equation-problem

Comment: @goblinb Thank you! Very helpful. A little unsure as to where the F ln(r) term came from, is it a part of the solution to the radial equation?

Comment: Yes, $R(r) = c_1 \ln(r) + c_2$ is a solution for $k = 0$, right? See section 7.2.1 in Tveito/Winther, referencing example 7.1. Have you done problem 4 yet? :)

Comment: @goblinb I see. I will read the section tomorrow and look at problem 4!

Comment: Let me know how it goes!

Comment: @goblinb At this point I have arrived at $ u(r,\theta) = E_m\ln r + \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\mathcal{A}e^{im\theta}(r^{-m} - r^m)$, where I just need to determine $E$ and $\mathcal{A}$ by taking the inner product $\langle u(r,0), sin(m \pi x) \rangle$ I suppose. Still haven't used the second boundary condition, though...

Comment: can't you use the second boundary condition to find the Fourier coefficients?